# I am using hapi-job-queue for certain cron jobs but having trouble with schedule?

Tags: node.js, cron, hapi.js

From the documentation of [hapi-job-queue](https://github.com/firstandthird/hapi-job-queue) I found that it supports the [Later](http://bunkat.github.io/later/parsers.html#text) style time definition in `schedule` params. So I tried like

```
server.register([
  {
    register: require('hapi-job-queue'), options: {
    connectionUrl: Config.database.url,
    endpoint: '',
    auth: false,
    jobs: [
      {
        name: 'test-job',
        enabled: true,
        schedule: 'at 04:59 pm',
        method: someMethods
      }
    ]
    }
}
]
```

But I think the code is not working.. if i try `schedule: 'every 5 seconds'`

everything works find and i even tried `schedule: 'at 5:00 pm'` which is a valid [Later](http://bunkat.github.io/later/parsers.html#text) style time definition. Am i missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code and it seems to work correctly. By the way you can verify the correct parsing of the timing you specified by just checking the 'Jobs' collection on the mongoDb instance you specified in 
    'Config.database.url'.

Look for the document having 'test-job' as _id field and check the 'nextRun' property; you should see the correct timing: '2016-08-13T16:59:00.000+0000' (in my case)

Comment: forgot to reply here bcz that worked long time ago :)